# Describing fists hitting faces

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, phrases, expressions

In Russian language there is a bold, threatening expression, describing your fists and the force of your blow. When you are saying that you are going to punch someone with your both fists badly, would the phrase "my right blow's final and the left one's feral" sound native/ok for an English-speaker's ear?

Or maybe there is something like that? (The Russian phrase is: "мой правый (right) - коронный (finishing/top quality, левый (left) - похоронный (will send you to the grave)")

Comment: This reminded me of a delightful German word "Backpfeifengesicht" which means a face that looks as though it is desperately desiring to be punched or slapped hardly.-- In other word's "a very punchable face"-- Though I have an overwhelming pride for the English Language, I must admit Germany surely can coin strange words better than our English tongues can--sometimes....

Comment: @TomO'Bedlam , in Russia we say "морда кирпича просит" - muzzle is asking for a brick

Comment: The only semi-standard threats I can think of are "Eh, you, your face my fist!" and "Are you looking for a slap?" Not really related but pleasantly colourful is "he's got a face like a slapped arse".

Comment: @TomO'Bedlam In French, you say "Tête à claques" which means the same as in German! I wish English had a word for an irresistibly slappable face too!

Comment: The Russian saying translates almost meaninglessly to English. We have something similar in “you’re asking for a bunch of fives”. It refers to a clenched set of fingers and a thumb, a fist.